# SQL Server trigger, insert shortened version of string

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I want to make a trigger that, when I insert a string into column A, a shorter version (max 117 chars) gets inserted into column B, both in the same table.

How would I do this using SQL Server 2014?

Comment: Skip the trigger, use a computed column instead!

Comment: In oracle we have something like substring function, see if you have a counterpart in SQL server.

Comment: This is not advised as it would be duplication of data. The shorter version should be calculated in a view or stored procedure when required.

Comment: If you insist on a trigger, please post your existing code and table structure, that will give you better responses.

Answer (score 5):

In SQL Server 2014, you don't need a trigger or even a second column storing the data.  Just use a computed column:

```
alter table t add b as (left(a, 117))
```

Comment: but this is not what i asked

Comment: @FastCow but what you asked is not a good way to do this. Triggers are truly awful beasts that quite rarely have much use in the real world.

Comment: Sorry to disagree with you but in the financial world triggers are used very extensively to control and audit changes. They are much, much slower then computed columns.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits . . . Triggers have their place.  But like cursors, they should be avoided especially when there are convenient, concise, and better performing work-arounds.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers are not advisable but you could use this

```
CREATE TRIGGER tx_Shorten
ON [YourTable]
AFTER Update, Insert
AS 
BEGIN 
IF (SELECT [YourColumn2] FROM inserted) <> (SELECT [YourColumn2] FROM 
deleted)  
BEGIN 
UPDATE [YourTable]
SET [YourColumn2] = (SELECT LEFT([YourColumn], 117))
FROM [YourTable]
END 
END
```